# Convert IIS web.config redirection rules to Apache .htaccess

Tags: iis, apache-2.4, .htaccess, redirect

I got to move an old PHP site from Windows IIS to Linux Apache server.
There are some redirection rules I have to convert.
Part of them I already managed, but for some other rules I lack the understanding to make them work.

There are the original web.config rules:

```
<rule name="Rule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^switch\.php$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^lang=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="switch/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="Rule2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^switch/([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="switch.php?lang={R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Rule3" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^zone-client/index\.php$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="zone-client/index" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="Rule4" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^zone-client/index$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="zone-client/index.php" />
</rule>
<rule name="Rule5" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^index\.php$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^slug=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="Rule6" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?slug={R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Rule7" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^index\.php$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^slug=([^=&amp;]+)&amp;details=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="Rule8" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?slug={R:1}&amp;details={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

And there are my trials to convert them:

```
#Rule1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^translation\.php(.*) /translation? [R=302,L]
#Rule2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^translation(.*) /translation.php [R=302,L]
#Rule3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=&$
RewriteRule ^switch\.php(.*) /switch/%1 [R=302,L,B]
#Rule4
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^zone-client/index(.*) /zone-client/index.php [R=302,L]
#Rule5
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^slug=&$
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*) /%1 [R=302,L,B]
#Rule6
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?slug=$1 [R=302,L]
#Rule7
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^^slug=&;details=&$
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*) /%1/%2 [R=302,L,B]
#Rule8
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ /index.php?slug=$1&details=$2 [R=302,L]
```

Please help!

Comment: Only a quick glance, but... `pattern="^slug=([^=&amp;]+)$"` - is that really correct regex syntax in the web.config file? Why is the `&` HTML entity encoded? (Is that necessary in web.config files?! It looks wrong to me, simply from a regex point of view, but I'm not too familiar with IIS.) The corresponding _CondPatterns_ in `.htaccess` are certainly wrong. You have a double `^^` on one of them. But a pattern like `slug=&` is only going to match when the query string is  `slug=&` which is unlikely what you intended. The web.config file uses a negated character class (so excludes a `&`).

Answer (score 1):

There is an online converter that take a web.config file as input and output the corresponding htaccess rewrite rules.

https://www.megacolorboy.com/posts/convert-iis-webconfig-to-apache-htaccess-using-javascript/

I have used it on a couple of occasions for simple web.config files and it works quite well!

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple steps you'll want to take to get your rewrites in place on the LAMP stack.

1. Make sure Mod_rewrite is installed and enabled for the webserver.

On an Apache 2 based server, run:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

This will activate the module or alert you that the module is already enabled. To put these changes into effect, restart Apache.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

mod_rewrite is now fully enabled.

Now you can setup an .htaccess file to define rewrite rules for redirects.

2. Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled using `RewriteEngine On` in your .htaccess and that it appears above your conditions and rules. 
   [For general info about rewrite rules in Apache- see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)

In your particular use case (switching from rules generated with the IIS URL Rewrite extension to straight Apache rewrites), you may want to check out some of these previous posts on stack overflow as examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591938/convert-web-config-file-to-htaccess
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936015/convert-iis-rules-to-apache-htaccess-rewrite

And in the case you want to doublecheck/test and debug your regular expressions, [use a tool like https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/)

3. Add your conditions and rules, be sure to indicate necessary flags on each rule.  (Most commonly, apply no case sensitivity with NC).  [See Apache's RewriteRule flags documentation at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)
4. Test your updated .htaccess rewrite rules. Be wary- a single typo in the .htaccess could result in a 500 error.